# Passing custom arguments as Command-line argument by running the MsTest.exe command prompt or via bat file

Tags: mstest

My need is to **Pass a custom arguments/Parameter to the unit test when running via the MsTest in the Command-line**.
The argument must be as command line argument and need to access the param value inside the test class or method.

Answer (score 1):

The MSTest command line does not support this option. Please look for a way to:

1. create a text or configuration file
2. start mstest
3. read that file from within your test.

A similar suggestion is posted in [MSTest Command Line Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889181/mstest-command-line-settings).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually i have to specify which config like Dev,Stage or Production like that and each have separate config files also. So, I need to pass the parameter like ["Dev"] or any option to specify run with specific config file specified in the mstest as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment to kroonwijk you said that you're trying to specify a particular config file to use in the test run. The way that I've handled this in the past is to create some App.config transforms (e.g., App.Test.config) where the "Test" part matches a configuration name that I set up in the configuration manager. Then, when I do a build with that particular configuration, the appropriate transformations are applied and the resulting config file has the values that I need for that environment.

Comment: I've used this approach too, however I'd like to come up with a way of doing it without storing sensitive information (such as username and passwords) in the transform files as I don't want them committed to source control. Did you overcome this at all?

Comment: @TheSenator We ended up building our own tool based on Microsoft.Web.Transform to transform the source config files to one appropriate for the target environment. The transform files are kept in a separate git repository that is more closely controlled than the rest of the source code.